# Creating a key in key vault using bicep modules failing with Bad Request error

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have got a bicep code which creates a key vault and I need to get it to create a key within the key vault, what I have found is that If the key is created at thesame time as the key vault, it works.

```
// create the stroage account key
resource storageAccountCmkKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: storageAccountCmkKeyName
  properties: {
    kty: 'RSA' // CMK only supports RSA keys
    keySize: 4096
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
      exportable: false
    }
    rotationPolicy: {
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          trigger: {
            timeAfterCreate: 'P5M' // 5 months
          }
          action: {
            type: 'rotate'
          }
        }
        {
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P1M' // 1 months
          }
          action: {
            type: 'notify'
          }
        }
      ]
      attributes: {
        expiryTime: 'P6M' // 6 months
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is modularise the process of creating a key. I want to have a module that creates a key when called and the parameters passed. To this note I have the module below.

From main.bicep

```
module Create_CMK './modules/create_cmk_in_kv.bicep' = {
  name:'Create_CMK'
  scope: resourceGroup('rg-inf-auto-dev-001')
  params: {
    keyName: cmk_key_name
    keyVaultname: keyvault.keyVaultName
    keyOps: cmk.keyOps
    keyType: cmk.keyType
    versionExpiryDays: cmk.versionExpiryDays
    rotateBeforeExpiry: cmk.rotateBeforeExpiry
    keySize: cmk.keySize
  }
  dependsOn:[createKeyVault]
}
```

for the create_cmk_in_kv.bicep

```
@description('The name of the Key vault.')
param keyVaultname string

@description('The name of the Key vault key.')
param keyName string

@description('The array of allowed key operations.')
param keyOps array = [
  'sign'
  'verify'
  'encrypt'
  'decrypt'
  'wrapKey'
  'unwrapKey'
]

@description('The key type.')
param keyType string = 'RSA'

@description('The key size.')
param keySize int = 3072

@description('The duration of the key expiry in days.')
param versionExpiryDays int = 180

@description('The number of days to rotate the key before expiry.')
param rotateBeforeExpiry int = 30



resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultname
}

resource cmkKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-02-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: keyName
  properties: {
    keyOps: keyOps
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
    }
    keySize: keySize
    kty: keyType

    rotationPolicy:{
      attributes: { 
        expiryTime: 'P${versionExpiryDays}D'
      }
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          action: {
            type: 'Rotate'
          }
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P${rotateBeforeExpiry}D'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I then get the error.

`The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'."`

Looking at the raw error, there isnt any detail as such.

```
 "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "code": "BadRequest",
      "message": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: on azure portal, can you check the deployment inner error please ?

Comment: Not sure if it will solve your error but 'Rotate' unde lifetimeActions should be 'rotate'. Also, a new API version is available: 2023-07-01

Answer (score 0):

> The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed: -

The above error usually occurs when you do not have a necessary permission to deploy the key vaults/keys resource. To make it work as expected, go to your `key vault >> Access Control >> Add a role assignment`. Add a `key vault administrator` role to the corresponding user.

You can also check the Activity Log to get enough information about the deployment errors and their status accordingly as shown below.

*Path:* `Resource Group >> Deployments`

[image]

Sometimes **"BadRequest"** error also occurs with the location perspective. If the provided location is not available due to some connectivity or server issues, the deployment will not work as expected and may lead to this kind of conflicts.

So, choose different `location` rather than the used one to resolve the issue.

Your code looks good to me. I tried deploying the similar code as you for `keyvaults/keys` using module in bicep and the deployment was successful as shown.

```bash
param keyVaultname string = 'newkvj'
param keyName string = 'newkj'
@description('The array of allowed key operations.')
param keyOps array = [
  'sign'
  'verify'
  'encrypt'
  'decrypt'
  'wrapKey'
  'unwrapKey'
]

param keyType string = 'RSA'
param keySize int = 3072
param versionExpiryDays int = 180
param rotateBeforeExpiry int = 30
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaultname
}

resource cmkKey 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-02-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: keyName
  properties: {
    keyOps: keyOps
    attributes: {
      enabled: true
    }
    keySize: keySize
    kty: keyType

    rotationPolicy:{
      attributes: { 
        expiryTime: 'P${versionExpiryDays}D'
      }
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          action: {
            type: 'Rotate'
          }
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P${rotateBeforeExpiry}D'
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
module Create_CMK 'keuvault.bicep' = {
  name:'Create_CMK'
  scope: resourceGroup('xxxjahnavixxx')
  params: {
    keyName: keyName
    keyVaultname: keyVaultname
    keyOps: keyOps
    keyType: keyType
    versionExpiryDays: versionExpiryDays
    rotateBeforeExpiry: rotateBeforeExpiry
    keySize: keySize
  }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/quick-create-bicep?tabs=CLI#review-the-bicep-file)